# Looking for name of door trim part

Tags: doors, trim, weatherstripping

I have an old door with what looks like a wooden equivalent to weatherstripping.  The door, and frame have mating parts that interlock.  I'm trying to figure out what its called, to have a chance at replacing a segment. Any direction would help (even a better search term)

Pictures...

Door side

[image: D]

Frame side

[image: frame side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this stuff is metal, known as "interlocking weatherstrip", but since that's not a great search term, it's often found in the same vicinity as "spring bronze weatherstripping". Check kilianhardware.com, under the springbronze tab.

Comment: This seems to be the right phrase to look for.  Thanks!